# Kamjanez-Podilsky to Lwiw?

Tags: ukraine, eastern-europe, shared-taxis

On 12th of February in the later afternoon I would like to travel from Kamjanez-Podilsky to Lwiw as I need to catch a plane in the morning.

I would like to go by train, but that's not an option. The arrival time is rather unsafe and I have to change the trains in the middle of the night.

http://ticket.bus.com.ua/order/forming_bn?point_from=UA6810400000&point_to=UA4610100000&date=12.02.20&date_add=1&fn=round_search which is recommended by rome2rio doesn't give any result at all. (despite writing 3 busses a day)

Is there any Marschrutka or how do the Ukrainians travel? 
Taxis are +130€ and I want to avoid that.

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the solution.

I fear I have to confess it's more a question of an [XY-Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). I mainly needed  to get to Katwice, but I really wanted to re-visit Lwiw. In the last days of my journey I found a solution and would like to share it with you. You have to understand I needed to be in Katowice in the morning of the next day, so my time-budget was limited.

I decided to take an early **bus** from Kamjanez-Podilsky to **Ternopol** (as I recall it it was at 8am and I arrived at 10am - there are earlier ones too. The ticked I obtained straight at the station the day before). I had around 3h to see Ternopol (which is not that many, but I enjoyed).

Then I took the **train** from Ternopol to **Lwiw** and arrived at around 5pm.

From here I beg you: Please be smarter than me!

**Don't do**: Stay in Lwiw over night and take the early flight from Lwiw to Krakow, then the bus to Katowice. Lwiw got pretty expensive and even a cheap hotel was not so cheap as in other parts of Ukraine. I forgot to do the check-in at in the evening and had to pay a penalty at the airport of 55€. From Krakow I got a Flixbus to Katowice. 
Also I sent my whole luggage from Kamjanez-Podilsky back home.
Total extra costs: Around 150 Euro.

**Do**: Stay in Lwiw from 5pm to 10pm and take the night train to Krakow. Then the morning train to Katowice. 
I used to do something like that back in 2009, but was not very happy about it. In retrospective of the current trip it's still *much* better.

Answer (score 1):

There are some results [on Yandex Timetables](https://rasp.yandex.ru/search/?fromId=c23169&fromName=%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%86-%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9&toId=c144&toName=%D0%9B%D1%8C%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B2&when=12%20%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8F).

Not sure if they are super accurate. Have you tried phoning the Central Bus Station of departure?

Comment: I'll call them on Monday, good idea

Answer (score 1):

I didn't see any results after 9th Feb, which is 15 days from now, so I went digging into the site's terms and conditions, where I found [this relevant bit](http://ticket.bus.com.ua/rules):

> 3.2.5.4. The extreme date of operations is determined by server of bus terminal (bus station, transporter). Of course it is not less than 15 days from current date.

So it appears that you can only book tickets 15 days or less from the departure date. A very strange restriction, but there you have it.

Comment: That's actually pretty helpful, thank you. I'll open it again tomorrow

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, no option seem to completely satisfy your criteria: trains require changing the train in the night, and buses depart in the morning and arrive on lunch time.

1. **Train.**
   [The timetable](https://www.uz.gov.ua/en/passengers/timetable/?station=22260&by_station=1) of Kamianets-Podilskyi train station shows that the only two trains are:

   - № 770 Kamianets-Podilsky — Kyiv (departure time 00:55)
   - № 118 Chernivtsi — Kyiv (departure time 23:57)

   Both make a stop in **Khmelnytskyy** (around 03:00 in the night) where there are [plenty of trains](https://www.uz.gov.ua/route_2/index.php?start_st=22260&fin_st=47548,23092,23081,23215,36921,23200&fs=%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BC%27%D0%AF%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%86%D1%8C-%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%96%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9%20(%D0%A3%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D0%B0)&ts=%D0%9B%D1%8C%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B2%20%D0%9C%D1%96%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%20(%D0%A3%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D0%B0)) heading to Lviv., including
2. **Bus.** There are two of non-stop ones:

   - departure 06:00, arrival 13:00
   - departure 09:45, arrival 17:33

   As another answer suggests, Web sites may not display routes/tickets earlier than 3 weeks ahead, but you can check one or two weeks earlier to see the expected schedule.

   Here are direct links to various ticketing companies; I've chosen February 5th for the reason above: [Busfor.ua](https://busfor.ua/%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%81%D0%B8/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BC-%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%86%D1%8C-%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%96%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9/%D0%9B%D1%8C%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B2?from_id=3809&on=2020-02-05&passengers=1&search=true&to_id=4037), [Bus.tickets.ua](https://bus.tickets.ua/en/search/result/98f288f221b36c9bb01ae70d1bd8989a), [Bilet-ua.com](https://bus.bilet-ua.com/order/forming_bn?point_to=UA4610100000&lang=en&date=05.02.20&date_add=3&point_from=UA6810400000&fn=round_search)

Usual caveat: many sites do not have proper English parts; use online translate tools.